# Ordered statistics: find $E(Y(i) Y(j))$

Tags: statistics, order-statistics

Let $Y1 ,…., Yn$ be independent, uniformly distributed random variables on the interval [0,1].

Find: $Var[Y_{(j)}- Y_{(i)}]$, the variance of the difference between two ordered statistics 
Where i and j are integers with 1≤i < j ≤n.

My Steps are:
1) find the joint density function. My answer:
$$\frac{n!}{(i-1)!(j-i-1)!(n-j)!}(y_{(i)})^{i-1}(y_{(j)}-y_{(i)})^{j-1-i}(1-y_{(j)})^{n-j}$$

where $0< y_{(i)}< y_{(j)}<1$

2) Find $E[Y_{(i)}Y_{(j)}]$ from first principle
$$a\int_{0}^{1}\int_{y(_{j})}^{1}y_{(j)}(y_{(j)}-y_{(i)})^{(j-i-1)}(1-y_{(j)})^{n-j}y_{i}^{i} dy_{(i)}dy_{(j)}$$

where $$a = \frac{n!}{(i-1)!(j-i-1)!(n-j)!}$$
This is where I am stuck. I am not sure how to integrate this integrand. Any tips/hints would be great. My aim is to convert this to a Beta form.

3)  Find $\operatorname{Cov}[Y_{(i)}, Y_{(j)}]$ using $\operatorname{Cov}[Y_{(i)},Y_{(j)}] = E[Y_{(i)}Y_{(j)}] - E[Y_{(i)}]E[Y_{(j)}]$. But this depends on step 2.

4)  Find the variance using the generic $\operatorname{Var}[A-B]=\operatorname{Var}[A]+\operatorname{Var}[B]-2\operatorname{Cov}[A,B]$ . However, this all depends on part 3 and the steps before it.

Please provide some guidance as to whether my overall approach is correct and what can I do to overcome step 2.

Thanks.

Edit: sorry for step 2 -> it should be $E[Y_{(i)}Y_{(j)}]$ not $E[Y_{(i)}-Y_{(j)}]$. Typing error.

Comment: your post says find $E[Y_{(i)}Y_{(j)}]$.  Do you need the product or the difference between the ith and jth order statistic?

Comment: Hi, in order to prove the variance of the difference between two ordered statistics, I need to first find the joint pdf (step 1). Next, to find the expected value, I have to multiply y(j)y(i) with their joint pdf.  Overall, my final aim is to find the variance of the difference between 2 ordered statistics (step 4). Not the  difference or the product between 2 ordered statistics.

Comment: I think your answer for the joint density might be wrong?  The joing density of two order statistics should be $\frac{n!}{(i-1)!(j-i-1)!(n-j)!}[F(y_i)]^{i-1}[F(y_j)-F(y_i)]^{j-1-i}[1-F(y_j)]^{n-j}*f(y_i)f(y_j)$

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you try and find $E[Y_{(j)}-Y_{(i)}]$ by using the linearity of expectation.  You don't need the double integral.
$$E[Y_{(j)}-Y_{(i)}]=E[Y_{(j)}]-E[Y_{(i)}]$$
Thus, the pdf for the $k$th order statistic is
$$f_k(y)=\frac{n!}{(k-1)!(n-k)!}y^{k-1}(1-y)^{n-k}dy$$
$$E(Y_k)=\int_0^1{y\frac{n!}{(k-1)!(n-k)!}y^{k-1}(1-y)^{n-k}}dy$$
$$=\int_0^1{\frac{n!}{(k-1)!(n-k)!}y^{k}(1-y)^{n-k}}dy$$
From here it is a bunch of integration by parts, or you rewrite the integral in one step:
$$=\frac{k}{n+1}\int_0^1{\frac{(n+1)!}{(k)!(n-k)!}y^{k}(1-y)^{n-k}}dy$$
Now the integral expression is just the beta distribution with parameters $\alpha=k+1$and $\beta=n-r+1$.  Thus the entire integral is just 1!  Hence
$$E[Y_{(j)}-Y_{(i)}]=E[Y_{(j)}]-E[Y_{(i)}]=\frac{j}{n+1}-\frac{i}{n+1}=\frac{j-i}{n+1}$$
Try seeing how far you can get now that you have this part....

Comment: Sorry but linearity of the expectation will NOT save the day here.

Comment: Yeah, I noticed....he had originally typed his question wrong so I was under the impression at least he was looking for that....

Answer (score 0):

Here's the solution generated by mathStatica/Mathematica …

Parent pdf:  let $Y$ ~ Uniform(0,1) with pdf $f(y)$, which we enter as:

```
f = 1;        domain[f] = {y, 0, 1};
```

The joint pdf of the (i, j)th order statistics, say pdf $g(y_{i}, y_{j})$, is given by:

```
g = OrderStat[{i, j}, f]
```

[image]

with domain statement:

```
  domain[g] = OrderStatDomain[{i, j}, f];
```

Part 3: $\operatorname{Cov}[Y_{(i)}, Y_{(j)}]$:

[image]

Part 4: The variance you seek is:

[image]

All done.

Comment: In the first line, please replace "solution" by "formula".

Comment: @Did Your comment is quite interesting, because it suggests a misunderstanding of computer algebra systems. In particular, mathStatica does not _know_ the _formula_ for the answer; nor is it pre-programmed in. Rather, the software has an algorithm for deriving the solution, and it derives it in much the same way that we might do it manually. The actual integration performed is mostly pretty mundane and boring ... unless you get a kick out of such things ... about as interesting as long division. Even then, one can see the integrals being performed, if that is your fancy.

Comment: *misunderstanding of computer algebra systems*... Funny that, even writing my comment, I was nearly sure you would resort to this cheap trick. So predictible! You know, some of us know exactly what a CAS does... Anyway, the fact is that your rendition of the net results of a CAS (the one you are interested in and are promoting relentlessly in many of your "answers" on MSE) fails to bring the understanding the OP explicitly states they are after. Net results **plus the steps used to reach them** would be another, more interesting, story.

Comment: Indeed, I have read through many of your answers now. While I understand that you have a desire to advertise your software, simply showing code entered and output given does not help the OP at all.

Comment: @mixedmath Sometimes, when you want to get from A to B, you want to know how to get there. And sometimes, you just want to get to B, because you are really interested in doing something at B or with B. Sometimes, you might not even know where or what B is (so knowing B can certainly help you!). .... Different people use different toolsets and different methods … that is what makes this site interesting … and as technology advances,  I think it is fairly self-evident, that at least for a subset of problems,  the best way of getting from A to B changes too.  ... cont .. ->

Comment: ---> [continued] One _can_ certainly get from Sydney to London mostly by bicycle, … some people might even want to, and it certainly could be fun and scenic … but it's not the most direct route. Computer software can help free us from the mundane, so that we can turn our attention to higher-order problems,  … and especially to those problems that computers are ill-suited to solving. Suggesting that people should continue to use long-division to prove that 23/7 = 3.28571… when better methods exist … would seem frankly absurd.

Comment: @mixedmath wrote: `you have a desire to advertise your software`.   .... ----> Not really. My main desire is the simplest path to getting there. If you would prefer people who post computationally-based solutions _not_ to mention what package/software is being used, please let me know … I would certainly be happy to just post the answers by the most direct route possible, without mentioning what products have helped generate the solution. This might also be an interesting subject for meta discussion.

Comment: *My main desire is the simplest path to getting there*. This is a lie. You do not show any path, only the final formula. As already mentioned: "Net results **plus the steps used to reach them** would be another, more interesting, story".

Comment: @Did If you are aware of a shorter path, that involves fewer steps ... I would be very pleased to adopt same. Behind the automated function, there of course exists a very large number of individual steps ... it is much more difficult and complicated to implement a function like OrderStat in a general way than it is to solve, say, just this problem manually step-by-step. The advantage, of course, is that once  the higher-order function has been set up, you can instantly solve arbitrarily many such problems. Do you manually check the addition on your supermarket bills? Or just pay the total?

Comment: Off-topic, as was to be expected. When invoking "a shorter path, that involves fewer steps", which path does "shorter" refer to? There is NO PATH in your post, just a statement of the final result. The code you copied is not a path, just a code. And this is all right as long as one does not falsely pretend that it is a "path". (Say, since you understood perfectly the first time and since all this is just some kind of damage control procedure on your part, I might not see fit to debunk your next obfuscation. "Case closed", as they say.)

Comment: No - the path is (a) to define the problem correctly, and (b) to then pick the appropriate tool. For _me_, the appropriate tool is an automated function designed to solve the problem:  it usually takes about 30 secs to set it all up, and about 5 to 10 seconds of computing time to solve. For _you_, it involves going back to basics and doing everything from scratch ........ If I got lost in the bush, and needed someone to help make a fire, it would be great to have you along. But until I get lost, and run out of matches, ... :) Happy hunting!